# Can I use ActionCable to refresh the page?

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-5, actioncable

I've recently been trying to create a live-scoring system for squash matches. I've managed to use ActionCable with Rails 5 to auto-update the score on the page, but I'd like to know if it's possible to tell Rails to refresh the page if a certain condition is met.

For example, if the game has finished, a different page is shown to say that the players are having a break between games. I need the page to refresh completely for this to happen.

In my database the boolean 'break' is marked as true when a game ends, and then the view uses a conditional if/else statement to decide what to show.

The code I use to update the score is attached below, I was thinking something along the lines of `if data.break == true` then the page will automatically refresh.

```
// match_channel.js (app/assets/javascripts/channels/match_channel.js)

$(function() {
  $('[data-channel-subscribe="match"]').each(function(index, element) {
    var $element = $(element),
        match_id = $element.data('match-id')
        messageTemplate = $('[data-role="message-template"]');


    App.cable.subscriptions.create(
      {
        channel: "MatchChannel",
        match: match_id
      },
      {
        received: function(data) {
          var content = messageTemplate.children().clone(true, true);
          content.find('[data-role="player_score"]').text(data.player_score);
          content.find('[data-role="opponent_score"]').text(data.opponent_score);
          content.find('[data-role="server_name"]').text(data.server_name);
          content.find('[data-role="side"]').text(data.side);

          $element.append(content);
        }
      }
    );
  });
});
```

I don't know if this sort of thing is possible, and I'm not much good at anything Javascript related so I'd appreciate any help on this.

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Reloading the current page is relatively straightforward. If you are using Turbolinks, you can use `Turbolinks.visit(location.toString())` to trigger a revisit to the current page. If you aren't using Turbolinks, use `location.reload()`. So, your `received` function might look like:

```js
received: function(data) {
  if (data.break) {
    return location.reload();
    // or...
    // return Turbolinks.visit(location.toString());
  }

  // your DOM updates
}
```

Either way is the equivalent to the user hitting the reload button, so it will trigger another GET, which calls your controller and re-renders the view.